# Python 2.7 - convert base 64 to binary string

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I'm using Python 2.7 (that means that there is no `base64.decodebytes()`)
I need to convert my base64 string, for example `aW0ganVzdCBhIGJhc2UgNjQgZmlsZQ==` into binary (i.e string of 1's and 0's).

I thought to try and write the base 64 string to a file in mode `wb` and then read it back with `rb` but even when used `wb` to write - I still see the original base 64 string when opening the file..

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the binascii library?

Comment: You are doing something wrong but you are not showing us the code you are using to write the binary to the file or the code which reads it back. Decoding a string of base64 results in a number of bytes with values in the range 0-255, not directly a string of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Great example string, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that conversion with the `ord` and `format` functions in a list comprehension.

```
import base64
data = 'aW0ganVzdCBhIGJhc2UgNjQgZmlsZQ=='
print [format(ord(c), '08b') for c in base64.b64decode(data)]
```

**output**

```
['01101001', '01101101', '00100000', '01101010', '01110101', '01110011', '01110100', '00100000', '01100001', '00100000', '01100010', '01100001', '01110011', '01100101', '00100000', '00110110', '00110100', '00100000', '01100110', '01101001', '01101100', '01100101']
```

If you want that as a single string, just `.join` it:

```
''.join([format(ord(c), '08b') for c in base64.b64decode(data)])
```

Comment: add a `content length checker` otherwise `base64.b64decode` will not work !

Comment: @dsgdfg Fair point. We could do a length check, but if we expect that the data will be valid most of the time then it's more efficient to wrap the code in `try: ... except TypeError:`.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. You can see the readable characters even if you save them into binary file. **Because they are ASCII characters.**

Actually, you are not going to save file with binary format, because you can't get the binary string by save it with 'wb'.

What you should do is to get the ASCII value of every character, and convert it to binary number.